# Error while removing custom entity in Crm 2011

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I can't delete a custom entity in MS CRM 2011 Rollup 11. While I'm trying to delete entity (it takes 5-7 min then there is an error) CRM freezes.

SQL profiler and DiagTool didn't give an answer. There were some errors, but they did not relate to the work of CRM. I've checked deletion of relationships, it's impossible too.

Comment: Have you enabled tracing? Are there any plugins/workflows installed that run against the entity being deleted?

Comment: I've disabled all plugins that could have influence on this process

Comment: Does it happen for **every** instance of that entity? Does it happen for **only** that entity? If you create an other custom entity that looks just like the problematic one (including all the plugins - by now deactivated, of course - workflows, relation etc.), does the problem appears there too? If you export the solution to a vanilla CRM, can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: I thought of one more - are there any scripts on the site? You might want to attempt deletion from a console application (i.e. make C# code delete an instance). If it works well, that's a strong indication against JS.

Comment: Just to be clear do you mean a record or an entity?

Comment: I mean an entity. I have tried to delete an entity with the help of metadata service, but the result was the same.(Crm freezing and not specified error)

Comment: Well I would suggest following @glosrob suggestion and enable tracing, we are going to find it very difficult to help you without a specific error message.

Comment: Usually each entity is connected to many other entities so you have to break any relationships that your custom entity had with other entities and then try to delete

Comment: Could you please provide detailed error description from CRM?

Comment: While I didn't have any errors, I recently helped a friend with a related issue using the `RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest` and `DeleteEntityRequest` messages.  Essentially, I recursively looped through his dependencies to delete the things tied to his entities.  In his case, this was the right solution.  In yours, you may have to be more gentle =/

Comment: what event viewer says?

Answer (score 1):

Once you install a managed solution you are not allowed to delete any of its entities, attributes, relationships, reports and OptionSets. This post provides a simple and supported workaround if you absolutely need to delete one of these components from a deployed managed solution.

Read this [link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/gonzaloruiz/archive/2012/05/07/crm-2011-deleting-attributes-entities-relationships-or-optionsets-from-managed-solutions.aspx) for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the custom fields and then try to delete the entity.